# JSONSchema: add extra constraints to property derived from ref

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a large library of JSONSchemas and I'd like to structure it as follows:

```
my_object.json # a canonical definition of my_object
create_my_object_response.json # a response to a request to create a particular my_object
```

In this setup, `my_object.json` would define a general format of `my_object`, while `create_my_object_response.json` would expect some particular values for the fields of `my_object`. I'd like to structure the `create_my_object_response.json` schema like this:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "my_object.json#" },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "id": { "const": 2 },
        "name": { "const": "A Specific Name" }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

`my_object.json` contains both the `id` and `name` properties but doesn't specify the `const` values. I tried this setup but it didn't seem to work. How can I represent this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Could you show the contents of `my_object.json`?  That will make this much easier to debug.

Comment: It might be helpful to look at https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/58 where people discuss the single value enum approach as well as the `constant` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure this out, so posting the answer here for posterity.

The construction I had was actually right, but instead of `"const": 2` I switched to `"enum": [2]`. I think this had to do with the version of the schema I was using.